# Any solution with environment APPLICATION_ENV into AppService IIS (azure)

Tags: azure, iis, zend-framework

I'm trying to setting this environment into AppServices from Azure but I guess this not work properly with .htaccess

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

Anybody knows how can config this?

I have IIS running in this AppService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use Azure api to do that, [here's an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common). In short: you need to go to configuration blade in the portal and define APPLICATION_ENV and set its value to `production`.